# instantiate a class object once and have the information globally available?

Tags: php

is it possible to only instantiate my class once and have the data that has been passed into my class available globally?

In my case I have a class called `Mail` and I'm instantiating it once on my main page. How can I get the information gathered by the methods available to other parts of my site without having to make a new `Mail` object?

On some of my files, i need to re include the `Mail.class.php` because they are outside the scope of the main include php page. But vital information has already been gathered into the already created object Mail. I need to access that information, and I don't want to dump the information into sessions either.

Comment: Search for the `Registry` or the `Singleton` design pattern.

Comment: Better not to search for singleton

Comment: not search? what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container. The basic principle is what you are describing: define an instance of a class as a service in your container, and allow it to be used from anywhere in your code that has access to the container.

The Symfony framework's DI component is available [as a separate component](https://github.com/symfony/DependencyInjection), or you can check out [Pimple](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple) as a lightweight example. These are two that I use; I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: which do you find more light weight and easier to implement and keep track of?

Comment: Pimple has 149 lines in its class file; the Symfony DI component is a full library. Unless you need advanced functionality, give Pimple a go.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of...

1) Use globals, do NOT do this.
2) Make your mail class a singleton, so whenever you instantiate it, you have the data you set.

Comment: A singleton in PHP is nearly in 99.9% of the cases a re-implementation of a global variable. So this answer is ambiguous, because on the one hand it suggests to not use global variables but on the other hand it suggest to encapsulate a global variable inside a singleton class. Hmm. Not very useful. Better read the full story: http://www.slideshare.net/go_oh/singletons-in-php-why-they-are-bad-and-how-you-can-eliminate-them-from-your-applications

Answer (score 0):

you can post the object in json format to other pages or you could make a temporary file/dbtable to hold the info. or sessions but that was not an option ;-). don't think its possible to do it in an other way. but hey, I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to only instantiate my class once and have the data that has been passed into my class available globally?

Yes, that's possible. Once you instantiated your class, it's an object assigned to a variable. You can pass that variable along in your program and then you have access to the object.

> In my case I have a class called Mail and I'm instantiating it once on my main page. How can I get the information gathered by the methods available to other parts of my site without having to make a new Mail object?

This is called dependency injection, other parts of your site have a dependency on objects of even other parts of your site. So you need to inject that dependency, e.g. as a function parameter for a simple example:

Main page:

```
$mail = new Mail;
other_part($mail);
```

Other part:

```
function other_part(Mail $mail)
{
     $mail; # there you have it
}
```

Comment: i wouldn't need to reference `$mail` as `&$mail` in the `other_part` function parameter?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to reference `$mail` as `&$mail`. You can safely pass objects along just as in the answer's example. That only was necessary in very old PHP 4 code.